# How do I add a background image to a div? I can't get it to work

Tags: html, css

I apologize for asking a fairly straightforward question that's been asked a million times, but I can't seem to get a background-image for a div. It worked on a different project I was working on, but I can't do it for this one. Is it maybe because I'm not getting the image from the correct folder/file?

```html
<style>
    .background-image {
        background-image: url("../images/food-background.jpg");
        padding: 100px;
        margin: 100px;
    }
</style>

<div class="background-image"></div>
```

[image: I'm doing this in the client folder under systemlayout.html.]

Comment: `<div class="background-image></div>` is that a typo or you really missed a `"`?

Comment: Just a typo, I had that in the code

Comment: Try setting width and height.

Comment: Unfortunately,  that didn't work

Comment: Use `dev-tools` to find the resulting width and height of the `div`

Comment: The div: <div class="background-image"></div> has no content, so it has width and height 0, so you can't see the background image

Comment: what's the filename?

Comment: Did you want to send me a URL and I can look? I feel like there must be something else

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned the filename. Assuming it is one of the HTML files. You need to locate the file as

```
background-image: url("images/food-background.jpg");
```

without `../`

Comment: No, `../` is perfectly valid for a relative URL; assuming that the URL is correct (obviously).

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah, but given the file structure, OP doesn't need it.

Comment: Ah, yeah: my bad, for some reason the image didn't load, or show a broken image, on my first read of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your path might be incorrect.

```css
body {
 background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
 
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: I honestly think that's what it might be, as I tried the same thing in a different project and it worked. Would you happen to know how to get to the correct path?

Comment: do you know how to use chrome developer tools?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: try images/... and NOT ../images/...

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, as well as most other recommendations. I'm just going to try and experiment with it and see why it worked for my other project but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

##### There are a few ways to do it...

**Here**:

- *color* is color in hex, reb, regba
- *path* is the path to the image
- *others* like position, attachments

---

### By ID

**HTML:**
`<div id="div-with-bg"></div>`

**CSS**:

```
#div-with-bg
{
    background: color url('path') others;
}
```

---

### By Class

**HTML:**
`<div class="div-with-bg"></div>`

**CSS**:

```
.div-with-bg
{
    background: color url('path') others;
}
```

---

### Inline

**HTML:**
`<div style="background: color url('path')"></div>`

---

Answer (score -1):

This could be happening for a few reasons. The first reason I can think of is your background .jpg is not in the folder you're writing all this code in? If not place it there. (So, it can actually find the background picture). My second reason would be your path to the jpg. Try and copy the path and past it right into the url(*here*). This should work assuming you're opening the file correctly. I think it is because you most likely don't have the image in the correct folder.